# Chrome keeps loading source map even after GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, source-maps

I've built an app with CRA and I'm trying to prevent Chrome from loading source maps.
Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Build react app with the command `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build`.
2. Ensure that no `.map` files are present in `/myprojectfolder/build/`.
3. Delete all static files in my AWS S3 bucket.
4. Deploy `build` folder to S3 using `aws s3 sync ./build s3://mybucket --profile=s3-admin`.
5. Invalidate AWS Cloudfront using `aws cloudfront create-invalidation --paths / /build /css/* /index.html /error.html /service-worker.js /manifest.json /favicon.ico`.
6. Clear all browser cache at Chrome settings.
7. Hard refresh with ⇧⌘R.

But it's still showing the message ***Source Map detected*** with the exact code I wrote. Also tested on Windows Chrome with the same result. Safari seems to have stopped loading source maps, on the other hand.

Did I do anything wrong? Or is there anything else I can do (maybe reboot)?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In order to fix this, I tried removing/adding hosting multiple times. I noticed that one of the old s3 hosting buckets still has .map files. So I removed the obsolete buckets and verified the current bucket doesn't have js.map files. Now I no longer see the actual source .js files in dev. tools including individual .css files.